# Why do some atoms like Mg have several ionization energy levels?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, quantum-chemistry

In [Dopant Energy Levels in Crystalline Silicon](https://www.globalsino.com/EM/page2777.html) (which asks for a password, but is partially readable if you click "cancel") appears the following image and caption:

> Figure 2777b shows the energy levels (also called ionization energies) of the main impurities in crystalline silicon (Si). The donor-like energy levels are indicated in green, and most of them are above the midgap and their values are given with respect to $E_c$. The acceptor-like energy levels are indicated in red, and most of them are below midgap and their values are given with respect to $E_v$. The elements which have both donor-like and acceptor-like energy levels are marked in blue.

[image]

Why do some atoms, like Mg, have more than one ionization energy?

Comment: What's the basis for ordering the elements like that?

Comment: Different charge states, different sites.

Comment: you should try chemistry stack exchange https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ . Unless you find a link with the plot that is open to all without passwords.

Comment: @annav - this is a solid state physics question, not chemistry.

Comment: You need to give more context here. Looking at the supplied link in the comments these are listed in terms of impurities in crystalline silicon and also goes over what the colors of the figure indicated. Please include more detail in your main post here.

Comment: @JonCuster do you have a link that can make the table above intelligible? the one given by the OP needs passwords and for a non solid state physicist cannot read it.

Comment: @annav - interesting... I see a PNG picture with doping levels in the gap for different elements, a much simplified table compared with that in Sze's book on Physics of Semiconductor Devices. The SE link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/myg3W.png

Comment: @JonCuster can you access this link that the OP has given  https://www.globalsino.com/EM/page2777.html  I get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource."

Comment: @annav - didn't try to access that (some random unknown to me) link. Looks like Rob edited a bit ago, pulling out the caption as well. Much more data is presented in various device physics textbooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various reasons for multiple ionization levels for impurities in semiconductors. For instance, silicon atoms in GaAs will occupy either a Ga or an As lattice site, and act as a donor (Ga site) or an acceptor (As site). Now, Si does not have non-equivalent lattice sites, so what is up with Mg?

Measurements of Mg in Si date to a [Solid State Communications](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0038109867905984?via%3Dihub) paper, R.K. Franks and J.B. Robertson, Solids State Communications 5, 4769-481 (1967). They compare their optically measured absorption lines for Mg in Si with theory. The results are in pretty good agreement. The theory numbers are calculated based on Mg sitting on an interstitial site, as Li does. Note that they consider the theory for Li (single donor) and S (also a known double-donor).

So, Mg (and S, and others) will donate two electons. The first, the weakest bound, is from a neutral Mg atom. The second, more deeply bound, comes off an Mg +1 ion. That leaves a Mg +2 charged ion with no more states in the gap.

A recent paper in [Phys. Status Solidi](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/pssa.201700192) (Yuri A. Astrov et al., Phys Status Solidi A 214 (7) 1700192 (2017)/ DOI10.1002/pssa.201700192) has more detail on Mg should you be interested.

Comment: @rob thanks for editing, the plot becomes understandable now, though  do not want to go into its particular  details